# Scrollable DIV controlled by exterior DIV (for touchscreen). jQuery HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DIV with some content inside it, when viewed on a touch device, the DIV which is quite large is wider than the dimensions of the screen. So I added the following CSS:

```
    #container{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto;
        background-color: blue;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

Which works fine, the DIV is now scrollable left and right while everything else on the page remains in place. My problem is that everything in the DIV responds when touched, mainly clickable buttons and such.

Is there any way to add another DIV outside the container DIV which could be used to move it back and forth? So a thumb sized DIV which could be used to scroll the container DIV side to side, but this thumb DIV is outside the container DIV. Maybe just hovering on its bottom border.

Hopefully this makes sense, any suggestions or guidance would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Setup a DIV with the following CSS:

```
#thumb_button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1000; /* Ensures its on top */
}
```

Then use JS to detect a click on that DIV to scroll the other DIV.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#thumb_button").click(function(e){
    $("#container").scrollLeft += 10;
  });
});
```

This is untested.

Also, maybe worth using a JS library like HammerJS to work with touchscreen devices more appropiately to detect a finger holding down the button to continue the scroll.